# What options do I have for popping up a list of dates when hovering over an HTML table cell?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, list, popup, hover

I have a client who has an ASP.NET MVC 2 application. One of the views contains a table with a "latest operation date" column. When hovering over that column with the mouse, they'd like a list of *all* the operation dates to be display in a pop-up panel (or similar).

There are generally between 0 and 5 dates to be displayed.

Seems like this will involve Javascript. If so, I'd like it to be unobtrusive.

Does anyone know of slick solutions to this? For example, any components out there that do a nice job? Or any sites that do something similar that I can look at for inspiration? Something like the pop-up when hovering over a tag on StackOverflow, for example.

I'm keen to improve my Javascript UI skills, so happy to put some of my own time in with a UI toolkit - even if the learning curve would usually be prohibitive for a small task like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly do this with jQuery. A simple solution would be to attach a hover event to the the column and load the operation dates via AJAX, to be displayed in the popup panel. A simple example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#yourcolumnid").hover(
    function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "URL",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{'PARAMETER':'VALUE'}",
        success: function(result) {
          $(document).append("<div id='alldates' class='CssForPopup'>" + result.d + "</div>");
        }
      });
    },
    function() {
      $("#alldates").remove();
    }
  );
});
```

This solution is, of course, unobtrusive and you could just put this all in a .js file and attach it to the page(s) you want to use it on.